# Combining two properties of a object in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js

I have a object array in javascript.
Example:

```
objArr = [{"FirstName":"John","LastName":"Doe","Age":35},{"FirstName":"Jane","LastName":"Doe","Age":32}]
```

I want to create an object array like this

```
newObjArr=[{"Name":"John Doe","Age":35},{"Name":"Jane Doe","Age":32}]
```

How should I do this?

Comment: Have you made any attempt at all yourself yet? Post what you've tried

Comment: Are we assuming name is unique on a list? And that first name + lastname is name?

Comment: Duplicate of [How to concatenate two string fields into one in a JavaScript array?](/q/34576386/4642212). Related: [Concatenate each object property values of javascript array , properties are list of strings in javascript](/q/71812690/4642212), [How to concatenate multiple properties of same element from an array?](/q/69056356/4642212).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Array.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

> The map() method creates a new array with the results of calling a
>   provided function on every element in the calling array.

```js
const objArr = [{"FirstName":"John","LastName":"Doe","Age":35},{"FirstName":"Jane","LastName":"Doe","Age":32}]


const newObjArr = objArr.map(({FirstName, LastName, Age}) => {
    return { 
      Name: `${FirstName} ${LastName}`,
      Age
    };
});

console.log(newObjArr);
```

Or an ugly one liner:

```
objArr.map(({FirstName, LastName, Age}) => ({ Name: `${FirstName} ${LastName}`, Age }));
```